# Googleway R Alternative routes

Tags: r, shiny, leaflet, google-directions-api, googleway

I'm using the google_directions() function to generate driving routes between two coordinates which are generated on clicking at different points in a leaflet map.I would like to show a few possible routes, instead of just one. Setting alternatives = TRUE does not seem to do the job for me. I've tried multiple coordinates.

```
    key <- "my_key"
    #lat1,lon1 generated on first click. lat2,lon2 generated on second click.
    df <- google_directions(origin = c(lat1,lon1),
                            destination = c(lat2,lon2),
                            key = key,
                            mode = "driving",
                            simplify = TRUE,
                            alternatives = TRUE)
    pl <- decode_pl(direction_polyline(df))
    leaflet() %>% addTiles() %>% addPolylines(data = pl, lng = ~lon, lat = ~lat,group = "route")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the [issue and have uploaded a fix](https://github.com/SymbolixAU/googleway/issues/144)

In brief, the `alternatives` argument wasn't correctly being used, as you found out.

If you install the latest development version this should work for you

```
devtools::install_github("SymbolixAU/googleway")
```

To show it working, this example will generate two routes

```
library(googleway)

set_key("api_key")

df <- google_directions(origin = "Melbourne Airport, Australia",
                        destination = "Portsea, Melbourne, Australia",
                        mode = "driving",
                        alternatives = TRUE)


df_routes <- data.frame(polyline = direction_polyline(df)) 

set_key("map_key", api = "map")

google_map() %>%
  add_polylines(data = df_routes, polyline = "polyline")
```

[image]

Comment: It works perfectly now. Thanks for the immediate response!

Comment: @Agalloch - no, thank you for finding & reporting (and using it) !